# How to make button "send report" on Error MsgBox?

Tags: excel, vba

[image: Error MsgBox]

Is there a way on this **errHandler** to place the button **send report** or something similarly, if someone gets an error that can be recorded somehow. This is the code that I use for errHandler:

```
On Error GoTo errHandler
```

....some code.....

```
errHandler:
    MsgBox "An Error has Occurred  " & vbCrLf & _
        "The error number is:  " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & _
        Err.Description & vbCrLf & "Please notify the administrator"
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to make your own form.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would be to change the `MsgBox` default buttons and test what button was clicked.

```
errHandler:
    If MsgBox("An Error has Occurred  " & vbCrLf & _
        "The error number is:  " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & _
        Err.Description & vbCrLf & "Would you like to send an error report?", _
        vbYesNo) == vbYes then
            send_error_report_function Err.Number
    End If
End Sub
```

[Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445082%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) has more about the details of what you can do with `MsgBox` on their website.

An alternative that would give you more control, and would require more development time would be to write your own form.

Comment: Sub or Function not defined?? and in this line ...vbYesNo) == vbYes then... without one = .   how to defined this, send_error_report_function

Comment: You have to write it.